# Gcloud : Authenticating with Service Account

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Authenticating with service account using **gcloud** 
We are using below command for activating service account using .json file.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account <service_account> --key-file <file_name>
```

After doing this we are able to deploy templates.
But we are not supposed to keep json file on server for authentication purpose.

Is there any other way of authenticating for deploying templates?

Is there any way to deploy templates using client secret and client id without using json file ?

Answer (score 0):

To authorize Cloud SDK tools without storing private key, alternatively use tokens, [see OAuth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2):

1. `gcloud init` on your local terminal, [see Run gcloud init documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/initializing#run_gcloud_init)
2. `gcloud init` on Compute Engine VM Instance, [see Set up gcloud compute documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#auth)

To avoid prompts, provide parameters for gcloud init in the command line (works only when `$ gcloud config set disable_prompts false`)

`$ gcloud init --account=[account-name] --configuration=[config-name] --project=[prj-name] --console-only`

For more details see documentation [Managing SDK Configurations](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/configurations) and [Managing SDK Properties](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/properties)

There is also Google Cloud Shell, with 5GB of persistent disk storage and no additional authorization required to use Cloud SDK, [see Starting Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/starting-cloud-shell)

To provide authorization you also can use [Cloud Identity and Access Management API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/projects.serviceAccounts.keys/get). You may also find helpful the [answer for similar question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43648929/authenticate-service-account-without-downloaded-key-on-google-app-engine)

Comment: Hi Pawel,
Got the concept of outh2. We are working on gcloud cli only, so we need to pass the authentication details via cli, without using apis or .json files

Is there any way to achieve it ?

Comment: Did you try to use `$ gcloud init`? I believe, it is what you are looking for.

Comment: gcloud init prompts for setting all the config, I am not expecting prompt in between.

Comment: Did you try to use Cloud Shell? There is no need to authenticate. It is free and you can easily upload you templates or store other json credential files if needed.

Comment: I can't use cloud shell, need to configure in my server

Comment: I did add example of gcloud init syntax in the answer. Does it work for you? Please be aware, that using this command that way, you also have to manage configurations as described in the documentation.

Comment: Executiong `gcloud init --account=<account> --configuration=default --project=<project> --console-only` 

After disabling prompt getting below error 
`ERROR: (gcloud.init) Invalid value for [disable_prompts/--quiet]: gcloud init command cannot run with disabled prompts.`

Comment: This is proper message for this command. To eliminate above issue use `$ gcloud config set disable_prompts false`